# help with cohomology of $\mathbb{P}^n$ relative to a NCD

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, hyperplane-arrangements

Let $H_0, \ldots, H_n$ be $n$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ with normal crossings and denote by $H$ the union of them. I am trying to understand why

(1) $H^n(\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C}), H)$ is one dimensional

(2) $H^n(\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})-H)$ is one dimensional

Let us begin by (1). This is what I managed to do. Applying the long exact sequence for relative cohomology one gets

$... \to H^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^{n-1}, H) \to H^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^{n-1}) \to H^{n-1}(H) \to H^n(\mathbb{P}^n, H) \to H^n(\mathbb{P}^n) \to H^n(H) \to H^{n+1}(\mathbb{P}^{n}, H) \to \cdots $

Assume for example that $n$ is even. Then $H^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^n)=H^{n+1}(\mathbb{P}^n)=0$ and $H^n(\mathbb{P}^n)=\mathbb{Q}(-n)$, so one gets

$0 \to H^{n-1}(H) \to H^n(\mathbb{P}^n, H) \to \mathbb{Q}(-n) \to H^n(H) \to H^{n+1}(\mathbb{P}^n, H) \to 0$

Now I should say something about $H^{n-1}(H)$ and $H^n(H)$. I guess I should use the fact that, $H$ being normal crossings, this cohomology can be computed using the complex
$$
\oplus_i H^\ast(H_i) \to \oplus_{i, j} H^\ast(H_i \cap H_j) \to \oplus_{i, j, k} H^\ast (H_i \cap H_j \cap H_k) \to \cdots 
$$ and also the fact that cohomology in degree $n$ or $n-1$ should be simple because I have $n+1$ hyperplanes. But I don't know how to continue. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can assume without loss of generality that $H_i$ are coordinate hyperplanes (exercise). Then $\mathbb{P}^n-H=(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$ which is homotopic to $(S^1)^n$. So hopefully (2) is now clear. (1) follows from (2) by duality.